# error while cloning a project in moovweb from commandline

Tags: moovweb

I am new to moovweb.  Using gitbash to login to moov server .  After logging in I try to clone a project created successfully at moov web site from gitbash(as admin). I get the below error

```
$git clone moov@git.moovweb.com:bharath2k5/wikipedia.git
ssh:connect to host git.moovweb.com port 443: Bad file number
fatal:could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Also this is my .ssh/config.

```
Host git.moovweb.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     PreferredAuthentications publickey 
     Port 443
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your computer failed to connect to the moovweb git server (`git.moovweb.com`) so it didn't even get to the authentication step.  I noticed you have a rule in your ssh config to use port 443 instead of 22.  Does your network block port 22 access?  It's possible that even with the configuration, git is still using port 22.  You can check by running the following command:

Best way to check is to run the following command in git bash:

```
$ ssh -vv moov@git.moovweb.com
```

That should give you a lot of information, including which port ssh is trying to use.

Anyways, you can force git to use port 443 on a particular project by changing the URI used to clone the project.  Try the following and see if it works:

```
$ git clone ssh://moov@git.moovweb.com:443/bharath2k5/wikipedia.git
```

If that works, it seems that the `Port` configuration in `.ssh/config` doesn't seem to apply to git operations.